# Meaning of zero load and full load in circuits

Tags: diodes

This might be straightforward but it has been tough to grasp for me. When a question says to calcualate the power dissipated by the Zener diode under zero load and full load. What exactly does the concept of load mean here? I know load can be thought of as a well defined output, then the circuit connected is load or the power consumed is. But then, what is zero load and full load?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, a *load* receives power from a circuit while a *source* delivers power to a circuit.

So a *zero load* receives zero power while a *full load* receives full power (whatever that is in a particular context).

Since either an open circuit or short circuit receives zero power, neither of these is a *full load*.

For a Zener diode regulator, which I assume is the circuit context here, zero load means open circuit.  Since there is no power delivered to the load, the zener diode power is maximum.

Full load must mean minimum power for the zener diode, not zero power, since there is some minimum current through to maintain the (more or less constant) zener voltage across.

This is due to the fact that a zener diode regulator is a *shunt regulator* which means that current is *shunted* (diverted) around the load in order to maintain the voltage constant across the output.

If the load is 'light' or open, more current must be diverted through the zener diode and thus, the power dissipation is more for the zener.

If the load is near 'full', less current is diverted through the zener diode and thus, the power dissipation is less for the zener.

Answer (score 1):

In the first image, there is no load so this would be a zero load. All the current that flows in the circuit must go through the R1 and the zener.

In the second image, a load is present. At full load, that would mean that maximum current draw that would go into the load. Now the current will flow through the zener and the load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2GMQV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: didnt even realize that this question was asked months ago

Answer (score 0):

Zero load means no current is going through the load, i.e. an open circuit. Full load means that all possible current is going through the load, i.e. either a short circuit or some arbitrary maximum current as defined by the situation or problem.

Comment: I'd think that "full load" means some maximum specified load current, but not a short circuit - but it really depends on how the situation is specified in the question/problem.

Comment: Fair enough. Amended.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear what is meant by load in your example: there is typically some voltage source (say a wall adapter) providing power to both the Zener+resistor and the other stuff hanging off the Zener-regulated voltage.  One might consider the Zener part of the load on the main voltage source, but it is not part of the load on itself.  The load as it is referred in your question means what is hanging off the Zener-regulated voltage.

Zero load effectively means there is nothing connected to the Zener-regulated voltage, or it's switched off by a FET, etc.  It does not mean there's zero load on the voltage source powering the entire circuit, because there's still current flowing through the Zener+resistor, which is a load on the source.